# How to pass multiple values through Hibernate using RequestParam?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am passing 2 parameters in my url: name and abbreviation. App works fine when using this URL that accepts single values.

```
http://localhost:8080/userSearch/locate?name=John&abbreviation=F
```

Now I need abbreviation to handle multiple values F, M.

Trying to use either of these URLs.

```
http://localhost:8080/userSearch/locate?name=John&abbreviation=F&abbreviation=M
http://localhost:8080/userSearch/locate?name=John&abbreviation=F,M
```

When passing multiple values I get an empty string, [ ].  I looked into the query and I don't believe the abbreviation is being set correctly in HQL parameter.  I see the F and M being passed to method and I attempted to make them strings using...

```
String resultString = Arrays.toString(status);
```

and/or

```
 StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < status.length; i++) {
       strBuilder.append( abbreviation[i] );
    }
    String resultString = strBuilder.toString();
```

**Code below:**

**Controller**

```
public List<Users> findUser(
  @RequestParam(value = "name") String name,
  @RequestParam(value = "abbreviation") String[] abbreviation
       throws Exception{

 List<Users> users=new ArrayList<Users>();
  users= userService.getUser(name, abbreviation);

 return users;
 }
```

**Service**

```
public List<Users> getUser(String name, String[] abbreviation)
 throws Exception {     
    return UserImpl.locateUser(name, abbreviation);
}
```

**Impl**

```
public List<User> locateUser(String name, String[] abbreviation ) throws Exception {

    String resultString = Arrays.toString(status);
    //or
    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < status.length; i++) {
       strBuilder.append( status[i] );
    }

    String statusResults = strBuilder.toString();

        StringBuffer sql = new StringBuffer();
        sql.append("select user, con "                          
                + " from User user, Contacts con "          
                + " where user.userId = con.userId");

            sql.append( " and user.name =:name " );

            //works with single value
            sql.append( "  and user.abbreviation =:abbreviation " );

            //does not work with multiple value
            sql.append( "  and user.abbreviation =:resultString " );


        Query qry = factory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(sql.toString());
        qry.setParameter("name", name);

        //works with single value
        query.setParameter("abbreviation", abbreviation);

        //doesn't work with multiple value (Returns an empty string [])
        query.setParameter("resultString", resultString);

   List<Object[]> userList = query.list();
```

How do I handle these two values coming in from URL?

**Update**

MS.  That worked.  Thanks.  After using ParameterList I got an ORA-01797: this operator must be followed by ANY or ALL.  SO I changed : to in.

Comment: Did you tried to use usename=John&abbreviation=F&abbreviation=M ?

Comment: perfect, glad that the answer was helpfull

Comment: @Sunny you might consider accepting/upvoting an answer that helped you resolve the issue. It would mark the question as resolved and give something back to the contributor

Answer (score 1):

if you use the

`http://localhost:8080/userSearch/locate?name=John&abbreviation=F&abbreviation=M`

and add parameters using the `setParameterList` method so

`query.setParameterList("abbreviation", abbreviation);`

all should work for you.

Also, note the proper use for list parameter `user.abbreviation in :abbreviation` as stated by @Roman in the comment below

Comment: Shouldn't the HQL part be changed from `user.abbreviation =:abbreviation` to `user.abbreviation in :abbreviation` or something like that?

Comment: exactly, that part is necessary as well, good catch. You've used a proper syntax as well

Answer (score -1):

Try changing `@RequestParam(value = "abbreviation") String[] abbreviation` to `@RequestParam(value = "abbreviation") String abbreviation`. Then split the string using `String[] args = abbreviation.split(",")`.